# Question about string convert datetime by format

Tags: c#

Env : c# core 6
I try use DateTime.ParseExact to Convert String to DateTime, but here throw exception like this:

> System.FormatException: 'String '2023-07-13 08:36:20 AM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

the string s is read from sqlite

Code here in C#:

```
string Dt_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt";
string s = "2023-07-13 08:36:20 AM";
DateTime.ParseExact(s, Dt_format, null);
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the character separator between time values for your culture?

Comment: Maybe not the cause of error but just as a remark: `HH` together with `tt` doesn't make too much sense, because `HH` stands for a 24 hour clock ...

Comment: `string Dt_format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt";`

Comment: yep, i'm agree with @Enigmativity, the problem here is the HH instead of hh

Comment: @LucaLaMalfa It's not . At least for this particular datestring, because `08` is a valid hour for `AM`. Same as `16` would be a valid hour for `PM`. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFYKui)  But `16` as hour in combination with `AM` or `08` with `PM` throws an exception ...

Comment: @Enigmativity While combining `HH` with `tt` doesn't make too much sense, as long as the value for the hours fits together with `AM/PM` it doesn't throw an error ... It only throws, if those values don't fit ... See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFYKui)

Comment: @derpirscher i understand what you tried to explain, but so, if you using tt doesn't make sense using HH, by convention HH is used without tt, although as showed below HH and tt fail only if the datetime not fit...

Comment: @LucaLaMalfa Yes, I agree it doesn't make sense (see also my very first comment) to use `HH` together with `tt`. But at least for the given example it's not the source of the error (but it could be for other, ill-formed timestamps)

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, I will fix the HH/hh Error to fit the tt format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may be due to the CultureInfo of your environment. The third argument of DateTime.ParseExact method that you are passing null is the culture specific format provider object that you tell the ParseExact method to use. Try passing CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for the third argument:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, Dt_format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: "This is human text" I get from https://copyleaks.com/ai-content-detector

Comment: Okay, I will try this part.